# get CommandArgument from GridViewRow asp webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

is it possible to get `CommandArgument` from `GridViewRow`?

in the for-each loop in button click event I need `CommandArgument`

example code:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in MyGridView.Rows)
   {
       ...
       string commandArgument = ?;
       ...
   }
```

Comment: Would you explain why you need that?

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid there is checkBox in each row. for each checkbox if it's selected then update the data which is bound to row

Comment: That is not how a CommandArgument works. You probably need `DataKeyNames`. However due to the lack of info it is difficult to say.

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments I understood your mission . You can solve this 
by creating Hidden Field for getting Id of table and you can access this id  when the checkbox is checked. Then do update on the basis of id. Here I am updating 
name column of grid view.

Sample:
**WebForm1.aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUpdate" runat="server" Text= '<%#Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label> 
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkbox" runat="server" />
                         <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

**WebForm1.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        {

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {

            if (row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkbox");
                HiddenField hdID = (HiddenField)row.Cells[0].FindControl("id");
                Label lbl = (Label)row.Cells[0].FindControl("lblUpdate");
                if (chkbox!=null)
                {
                    if(chkbox.Checked)
                    {
                        string Id = hdID.Value;
                        //now update name...  here by the help of this RowId===> Id
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Note here Cells[0] means first TemplateField data. And I have used this because I have placed all name field and checkbox field in first templatefield.

I think this will help you. :)